# Extract a string variable from elf/obj file

Tags: elf, binutils

I'm trying to extract a particular string variable (i.e. symbol) from a Linux program's elf file, or even from the .o it comes from.
It's in the .rodata section, and obviously I know the symbol name.
Is there a sequence of objdump-style commands and options I can use to dump out the string?

Update:

For example, the .map file includes:

```
.rodata.default_environment 0x000000001013f763 0x615 common/built-in.o
                            0x000000001013f763    default_environment
```

The variable itself - `default_environment` - is a standard null-terminated text string.

Comment: Could you show how the value is represented in the object file or at the source code level? The proper approach depends on that.

Comment: Hi, unsure of the best way to show it but, for example, the .map file includes:
.rodata.default_environment
0x000000001013f763      0x615 common/built-in.o                0x000000001013f763                default_environment

The variable itself - "default_environment" - is a standard null-terminated text string. [Sorry - don't understand how to simply paste text into the reply on here!]

Comment: you can edit your post to include this information. It would also be interesting to know how the source code for `default_environment` looks like—if it is an array or a pointer.

Comment: const uchar default_environment[] = { "some text" };

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a sequence of objdump-style commands and options I can use to dump out the string?

Sure. Let's construct an example:

```
const char foo[] = "Some text";
const char bar[] = "Other text";

const void *fn1() { return foo; }
const void *fn2() { return bar; }

$ gcc -c t.c
```

Suppose we want to extract contents of `bar[]`.

```
$ readelf -Ws t.o | grep bar
    10: 000000000000000a    11 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    5 bar
```

This tells us that the "contents" of the `bar` variable is in section 5, at offset `0xa`, and is 11 bytes long.

We can extract the entire section 5:

```
$ readelf -x5 t.o

Hex dump of section '.rodata':
  0x00000000 536f6d65 20746578 74004f74 68657220 Some text.Other 
  0x00000010 74657874 00                         text.
```

and indeed find the string we are looking for. If you really want to extract just the contents of `bar` (e.g. because the `.rodata` is really large, and/or because `bar` contains embedded `NUL`s):

```
$ objcopy -j.rodata -O binary t.o t.rodata    # extract just .rodata section
$ dd if=t.rodata of=bar bs=1 skip=10 count=11 # extract just bar

11+0 records in
11+0 records out
11 bytes (11 B) copied, 0.000214501 s, 51.3 kB/s
```

Look at result:

```
$ xd bar
000000   O   t   h   e   r       t   e   x   t nul                              O t h e r   t e x t .
```

QED.